# Java: How to remove objects from an Array depending on the condition?

Tags: java, iteration

I have an array of Objects (file list excatly). How to iterate through this array and delete some Objects (in Java) - depending on the condition ?

```
File[] files = file.listFiles();
for(File f: files) {
   if(someCondition) {
       // remove
   }
}
```

Comment: You should not delete element from an array while iterating on it. It might result in wrongIndexing.

Comment: @Harry Joy, you are thinking of a List. In an array you may change the object with null/overwrite it with the next object, but you can't delete a position as arrays cannot be resized.

Comment: @Harry Joy: You haven't learned the lesson well. Wwhat you are saying applies when you are iterating through _Collection_ (not array) using Iterator, and removing elements by other means (let say `list.remove()`)

Comment: Convert it in to  a List type and do whatever you like to and then reassign it to your array.

Comment: @SJuan76 , @Op De ZCirkel: My bad. I apologize.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the best Java way to tackle your problem is to convert your array into a list and use an iterator which allows you to remove objects:

```
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()));
Iterator<File> iterator = files.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    File currentFile = iterator.next();
    if(someCondition){
        iterator.remove();
    }
    // other operations
}
```

You can even convert it again into an array if necessary -even though handling a list is probably more convenient ...:

```
File[] filesArray = files.toArray();
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but iterator.remove() will fail with the array-backed list returned by Arrays.asList(). You need to do the more cumbersome: `List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()));` if you want to add or remove items.

Answer (score 3):

You may be better off giving FilenameFilter to `listFiles` and apply condition there. See File documentation http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 3):

We can't *delete* elements and *resize* the arrays in one step/operation. Arrays can't be resized.

Either use a `List` or (1) flag the elements you want to delete and (2) write the elements you want to keep, to a new array.

Here's a solution if you *want* to continue with arrays (`List` is much easier):

```
private File[] filter(File[] files) {
  boolean[] deleteFlags = new boolean[files.length];
  int deleteCounter = 0;

  // collection
  for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (deleteConditionIsTrue()) {
       deleteFlags[i] = true;
       deleteCounter++;
    }
  }

  // create result
  File[] result = new File[files.length-deleteCounter];
  int gapCounter = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < deleteFlags.length; i++) {
    if (deleteFlags[i]) {
      gapCounter++; // skip entry, has been filtered/deleted
    } else {
      result[i-gapCounter] = files[i];
    }          
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the index of the object in the array to be able to remove it:

```
File[] files = file.listFiles();
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if(someCondition) {
        files[i] = null;       
    }
}
```

Note that an array has a fixed length. Removing an element won't shrink the array. If you want this, use a `List<File>`, iterate through the list using an `Iterator`, and use the iterator's `remove` method to remove the current element.

Comment: This requires some additional logic in other places because now we have to test for `null` everytime we want to use an array element. And I guess, he wanted to *resize* the array rather then replacing values with `null`. But that's just a guess...

Comment: I added some explanations regarding this problem in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

JB Nizet has it exactly right:

1. You can't "delete" elements from an array
2. You *can* set elements to "null".  This effectively deletes them (in a C kind of way), but it requires extra logic so you don't accidentally try to reference a null element.
3. All things being equal, you're probably better off with a List<>, which *does* allow you to insert and delete elements.

PS:
If you know a priori what elements you don't want, the FileFilter idea is an excellent way to keep from getting them in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to convert it to list and use LambdaJ filter operation: 
http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures. Also filter for lists is available in other libraries, like Guava.