# IndexOutOfBoundsException because of Apache common.lang ArrayUtils.remove

Tags: java, arrays, apache, indexoutofboundsexception

Code :

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;

int[] arr = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        int index = 0;
        for (int whit : arr) {
            if (whit % 2 == 0)
                arr = ArrayUtils.remove(arr, index);
            index++;
        }
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Length: 4
```

Java Version : **1.7**

Could anyone please help me to loop the same safely? 
Thanks in advance.

I referred most of the questions here for array and nothing helped.

It looks simple but its not working.Please comment the problem if its wrong.

Comment: The `remove` method shifts all subsequent elements to the left, so your indexes become irrelevant, and you get to a point where you refer to a non-existing (anymore) index. This question will help you do it in another way : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646888/java-how-to-remove-objects-from-an-array-depending-on-the-condition

Comment: You can iterate the array from right to left setting `index` to `arr.length-1` and reducing it in the loop with `index--`. That way the shifting to the left won't be a problem anymore as all elements that shift will already have been handled by your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change you code because when you remove the number from array, you dont't have to increase index counter:

```
        int index = 0;
        for (int whit : arr) {
            if (whit % 2 == 0)
                arr = ArrayUtils.remove(arr, index);
            else 
                index++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a lot more easily with an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html).

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
arr = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(n -> n%2!=0).toArray();
```

Result:

```
{3, 5, 7}
```

If you can't use streams, here is a way you can make your code work:

```
int index = 0;
while (index < arr.length) {
    if (arr[index] % 2 == 0) {
        arr = ArrayUtils.remove(arr, index);
    } else {
        ++index;
    }
}
```

Note that you don't increment `index` if an element has been removed, because all the subsequent elements have just been shifted back one place.

Comment: Thanks bro.just now updated the question for version.It should be in 1.7.sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Noobie OK. I've given another approach in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using for loop you can do like:

```
    int[] arr = new int[]{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
        int whit = arr[index];
         if (whit % 2 == 0) {
            arr = ArrayUtils.remove(arr, index);
            index--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will skip an element after you remove one, because `index` gets incremented every time, and all the subsequent elements got shifted left.

Comment: thanks @khelwood. Edited it. Your answer (while loop) https://stackoverflow.com/a/44780053/4041711 is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also work with  do-while-loop:

```
    int[] arr = new int[]{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

    int index = 0;
    do{
        if (arr[index] % 2 == 0) {
            arr = ArrayUtils.remove(arr, index);
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    }while(index < arr.length);
```

Comment: This will skip an element after you remove one, because `index` gets incremented every time, and all the subsequent elements got shifted left.

Comment: Sorry forgot the else block. Nevertheless it would have worked if the array is in that specific order: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

Answer (score -1):

After submitting my answer, I saw that you changed your initial post to only include Java 1.7 - however mine is for 1.8. I just wanted to mention this.

1. You can turn an array into a stream by using Arrays.stream().
2. You can filter by calling the stream methods with a Lambda function.
3. You then call toArray() to convert it back into an array.

   ```
   import java.util.Arrays;

   int[] arr = new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
   arr = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(a->a%2==0).toArray();

   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
   ```